# SQL Case statements, making sub selections on a condition?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case

I've come across a scenario where I need to return a complex set of calculated values at a crossover point from "legacy" to current.

To cut a long story short I have something like this ...

```
with someofit as
(
   select id, col1, col2, col3 from table1
)

select someofit.*, 
  case when id < @lastLegacyId then
    (select ... from table2 where something = id) as 'bla'
   ,(select ... from table2 where something = id) as 'foo'
   ,(select ... from table2 where something = id) as 'bar'
  else
    (select ... from table3 where something = id) as 'bla'
   ,(select ... from table3 where something = id) as 'foo'
   ,(select ... from table3 where something = id) as 'bar'
  end
from someofit
```

No here lies the problem ...
I don't want to be constantly doing that case check for each sub selection but at the same time when that condition applies I need all of the selections within the relevant case block.

Is there a smarter way to do this?

if I was in a proper OO language I would use something like this ...

```
var common = GetCommonSuff()

foreach (object item in common)
{
   if(item.id <= lastLegacyId)
   {
      AppendLegacyValuesTo(item);
   }
   else
   {
      AppendCurrentValuesTo(item);
   }
}
```

I did initially try doing 2 complete selections with a union all but this doesn't work very well due to efficiency / number of rows to be evaluated.

The sub selections are looking for total row counts where some condition is met other than the id match on either table 2 or 3 but those tables may have millions of rows in them.

The cte is used for 2 reasons ...

firstly it pulls only the rows from table 1 i am interested in so straight away im only doing a fraction of the sub selections in each case.

secondly its returning the common stuff in a single lookup on table 1

Any ideas?

EDIT 1 :

Some context to the situation ...

I have a table called "imports" (table 1 above) this represents an import job where we take data from a file (csv or similar) and pull the records in to the db.

I then have a table called "steps" this represents the processing / cleaning rules we go through and each record contains a sproc name and a bunch of other stuff about the rule.

There is then a join table that represents the rule for a particular import "ImportSteps" (table 2 above - for current data), this contains a "rowsaffected" column and the import id

so for the current jobs my sql is quite simple ...

select 123 456
from imports
join importsteps

for the older legacy stuff however I have to look through table 3 ... table 3 is the holding table, it contains every record ever imported, each row has an import id and each row contains key values.

on the new data rowsaffected on table 2 for import id x where step id is y will return my value.

on the legacy data i have to count the rows in holding where col z = something

i need data on about 20 imports and this data is bound to a "datagrid" on my mvc web app (if that makes any difference)

the cte i use determines through some parameters the "current 20 im interested in" those params represent start and end record (ordered by import id).

My biggest issue is that holding table ... it's massive .. individual jobs have been known to contain 500k + records on their own and this table holds years of imported rows so i need my lookups on that table to be as fast as possible and as few as possible.

EDIT 2:

The actual solution (suedo code only) ...

```
-- declare and populate the subset to reduce reads on the big holding table
declare table @holding ( ... )
insert into @holding
select .. from holding

select 
   ... common stuff from inner select in "from" below
   ... bunch of ...
   case when id < @legacy then (select getNewValue(id, stepid))
   else (select x from @holding where id = ID and ... ) end as 'bla'
from

(
   select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by importid desc) as 'RowNum'
   , ...
) as I
-- this bit handles the paging
where RowNum >= @StartIndex
and   RowNum < @EndIndex
```

i'm still confident i can clean it up more but my original query that looked something like bills solution was about 45 seconds in execution time, this is about 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I take it the subqueries must return a single scalar value, correct?  This point is important because it is what ensures the LEFT JOINs will not multiply the result.

```
;with someofit as
(
   select id, col1, col2, col3 from table1
)

select someofit.*, 
  bla = coalesce(t2.col1, t3.col1),
  foo = coalesce(t2.col2, t3.col2),
  bar = coalesce(t2.bar, t3.bar)
from someofit
left join table2 t2 on t2.something=someofit.id and somefit.id < @lastLegacyId
left join table3 t3 on t3.something=someofit.id and somefit.id >= @lastLegacyId
```

Beware that I have used `id >= @lastLegacyId` as the complement of the condition, by assuming that id is not nullable. If it is, you need an IsNull there, i.e. `somefit.id >= isnull(@lastLegacyId,somefit.id)`.

---

Your edit to the question doesn't change the fact that this is an almost literal translation of the O-O syntax.

```
foreach (object item in common)  --> "from someofit"
{
   if(item.id <= lastLegacyId)      --> the precondition to the t2 join
   {
      AppendLegacyValuesTo(item);   --> putting t2.x as first argument of coalesce
   }
   else                              --> sql would normally join to both tables
                                     --> hence we need an explicit complement
                                     --> condition as an "else" clause
   {
      AppendCurrentValuesTo(item);    --> putting t3.x as 2nd argument
                                      --> tbh, the order doesn't matter since t2/t3
                                      --> are mutually exclusive
   }
}

function AppendCurrentValuesTo     --> the correlation between t2/t3 to someofit.id
```

Now, if you have actually tried this and it doesn't solve your problem, I'd like to know where it broke.

Comment: this would likely work on the current data but im not sure about the old legacy stuff ... having said that ... let me update the question a bit

Comment: might also be worth noting that the id is a primary key

Comment: ah thanks ... that makes more sense ... my difficulty is my weak sql knowledge level ... im more confident in my C# / linq type querying.

Comment: The result of a join in my scenario represented  whole other problem ... i need a specific value (total rows where condition x is met) then (total rows where condition y is met) by joining i get a row for ech condition but then none represent my required output, more a single value from each row (my conditions). For that reason I had to think of another way round or face the problem how to disect the bigger rowset and pull only the values i needed.

Comment: It did occur to me to use something like a pivot ... but I didn't like the idea because "power users" are meant to be able to update add or remove the various sub selections in the future and a pivot would make the sproc more complex ... im not even convinced im clued up enough on sql to actually figure out the right syntax for a pivot anyway lol ... Cheers for the advice though ... just talking about it seems to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know that there are no conflicting ID's between the two tables, you can do something like this (DB2 syntax, because that's what I know, but it should be similar):

```
with combined_tables as (
    select ... as id, ... as bla, ...as bar, ... as foo from table 2
    union all
    select ... as id, ... as bla, ...as bar, ... as foo from table 3
)
select someofit.*, combined_ids.bla, combined_ids.foo, combined_ids.bar
    from someofit
    join combined_tables on someofit.id = combined_tables.id
```

If you had cases like overlapping ids, you could handle that within the combined_tables() section

Comment: this reminds me of my previous attempt at this query ... that union statement results in a query that takes about 30 seconds to run on my sample data (a subset of live data) ... i can't see it making the query efficient enough, but an intersting idea if I can join the 2 "non common" sets of data somehow in to a temp table or something then join that on my cte

Comment: @Wardy, it all depends on your data, specifically which tables are bigger.  This would probably be an efficient solution if table1 was bigger than table2 and table3.  However, if table2 and table3 are bigger than table1, it adds extra overhead.

Comment: You are of course right, the key is the table size, hense my reasoning for pulling a subset of the biggest table. The other tables aren't expected to be that big by a long way. I guess my question was really ... how can repeatedly query a subset of that big holding table in the fastest possible way ... the answer of course ... pull a subset then either join or sub query on that rather than the actual table. Cheers for the advice :)